# C# WPF Attachments from listbox to outlook attachment

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, listbox

Forgive me I am new to coding. I have the drag and drop working the way I want but what I need to know is how to pull from the listbox and have it send as an attachment with outlook after the user drops the file in the listbox. This is what I have so far.

```
private void AttachmentBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] DropPath = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
            foreach (string dropfilepath in DropPath)
            {
                ListBoxItem listboxitem = new ListBoxItem();
                if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(dropfilepath).Contains("."))
                {
                    listboxitem.Content = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(dropfilepath);
                    listboxitem.ToolTip = DropPath;
                    AttachmentBox.Items.Add(listboxitem);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now this is where I seem to be stuck. It will not attach anything that is in the listbox.

```
 //Add Attachment from Listbox
                    if (AttachmentBox.Items != null)
                {
                    Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add(AttachmentBox.Items);
                }
```

I get an error saying "Sorry, Something went wrong please try again". I would think converting all items in the list box to text might work but is there a better way?

Comment: You're assumption is right, you told it to add the list of strings, not the actual files.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Thanks me!

```
foreach (string fileLoc in myAttachmentPaths)
                    {
                        //attach the file
                        Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add(fileLoc);
                    }
```